# Can i query land area of a polygon in kmsquare from overpass api?

Tags: overpass-api

How can I query land area of a polygon, area, or city in kmsquare with overpass-api?
There is an example in Google maps below:

[image]

Comment: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/66892/how-to-calculate-area-of-polygons-in-overpass

Comment: You don't need Overpass for this, any reasonable GIS library will do. Try searching on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ first.